# NSWindow appears inactive but still accepts keyevents

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm building a status bar app (windowless) on OSX and having trouble with a pesky little UI bug.

The application opens up a preferences window from the status bar menu when a certain menu item is clicked.  The bug presents after the following scenario:

1. A user opens the preference window from the status bar menu
2. App resigns the active status when the user opens a browser or another app
3. User clicks the status bar item (to look at some info in the menu) but doesnt click the menuitem to show the preferenceswindow
4. User closes the other application and clicks on the already opened preferences window again

After this sequence the NSWindow representing the preferences window **appears** inactive while still accepting key events. By inactive I mean that the close button for the preferences NSWindow is gray unless hovered over, all the textfields don't get a blue focus ring when clicked and buttons with `keyEquivalent = "\r"` are not blue. The status bar item will also not highlight. It's like some other hidden window is hijacking the visuals of an active window.

This is what the preferences window looks like normally:
[image: Normal NSWindow]

This is what it looks like after the scenario I just described:
[image: NSWindow not active]

How do I make it so that when the preferences NSWindow **looks** active when clicked even if the user has used other apps and clicked the status bar item in the meantime? Note that the window accepts keyevents normally, and the application is active. Even just a step further in how to debug this would be helpful. Ive logged the main/key window and the apps active status in multiple places and everything looks right.

Comment: It would be much easier for someone to help if you provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Apparently the NSMenu pop up from the statusbar blocks the execution of the application code. Somehow the NSMenu was retaining the focus even if the menu had been closed if the application wasn't active.

Solution was to activate the app if windows are open when clicking on the NSMenu before popUpMenu is called. Note that the popUpMenu must be done slightly later to not block the activation of the app.  Something like:

```
let noWindowsOpen = extraVisibleWindows.count == 0

if (!noWindowsOpen) {
    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
}

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.04, repeats: false) { _ in
    self.statusItem.popUp(self.menu)
    
}
```

I found the solution on Github for another app that was dealing with similar [problems](https://github.com/p0deje/Maccy/blob/master/Maccy/Maccy.swift#L308).